# Disable touch Achartengine

Tags: android, android-layout, achartengine

Is it possible to disable the motion events on the charts draw using `Achartenigne`?. I am mapping a chart on a `linearlayout` instead of the chart taking the touch/click event i wish the handle the touch on `linearlayout`(as linear layout is child to another layout).

**Any help or suggestion is appreciated**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to disabled pan and zoom, you need to do:

```
renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
```

Comment: thanks buddy it worked it also tried it but didnt applied both methods.